# Laravel LogAuthenticated listener handle() error

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error while trying to get user model after authentication event

> local.ERROR: Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Listeners\LogAuthenticated::handle() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

Here is what my listener file looks like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use Carbon;
use User;
use Auth;

class LogAuthenticated
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle($event)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $userId = $user->user_id;

        echo $userId;
    }
}
```

The listener event gets executed fine when the user logs in, but then it gives an error when I try to look up the ID of the user. I can't figure out why.

[The documentation on handle() method in listeners doesn't mention how to handle Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-listeners)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you are using default table structure, `Auth::id()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
namespace App\Listeners;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue; 
use User; 
use Auth; 
 use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated;


class LogAuthenticated { 
public function __construct() {  } 

public function handle(Authenticated $event) {
 $user = $event->user; 
echo $user->id; 

} 

}
```